# Dell API for firmware information

Tags: dell

I am trying to implement Dell updates on our infrastructure.

I need to know if there is a good method for retrieving information about latest versions and maybe a compatibility matrix.

DSU does this already, but because of our requirements, we cannot use DSU. DSU is performing this logic itself, but I'm thinking it reaches out to an API for this information.

Anyone have insight into this? Thank you!

Comment: What server generation and iDRAC firmware level are you on?

Comment: We mostly deal with gen13. And iDRAC fw level depends on what the customer requests. (Which isn't always the latest)
I'm basically re-writing the functionality of DSU to fit our needs.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you've got two options, one much better than the other.

1. Query via WS-MAN (most compatible, most painful)

Going into exactly how to do this is ... way more than would fit here. But I believe the value you want is in the [iDRAC Card Profile](http://en.community.dell.com/dell-groups/dtcmedia/m/mediagallery/20066948/download.aspx) (warning PDF)

The full [DCIM Library](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/1839) has links to all the profiles and is a good starting point.

2. **IF** you are on firmware 2.30.30.30 you can use [RedFish](http://redfish.dmtf.org/).

For this you would make a simple GET request to (assuming rack server not blade chassis) `https://$server/redfish/v1/Managers/iDRAC.Embedded.1` and Grab the "FirmwareVersion" from the json. It's authenticated route so you would need to pass the username/password combo. You can also get an authkey, but that is more involved and is useful for batch operations against one server.

The [Dell Redfish Reference Guide](http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/idrac7-8-lifecycle-controller-v2.40.40.40_API%20Guide_en-us.pdf#GUID-4ECE141E-53DC-4D5D-BDF9-631C3A5C093B) can get you started. NOTE: this is for 2.40.40.40 so there may be routes not available to you at lower revisions. The firmware versions between 2.30.30.30 and 2.40.40.40 are bugfix, 2.40.40.40 introduces some OEM Extentions to import and export the iDRAC config.

EDIT:

Sigh totally misread your question. I'd look into [Dell repository manager](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=9RX9M)

You can also sign up for RSS feeds, but I think pulling down custom repos and having a scheduled search in Dell Repo Manager will be the best you can do.

Comment: I looked into the DRM method. I really like this, however storage space would be an issue for us. We would require many, many different bundles for different machines.
I think pulling this info from an RSS feed and manually defining which update packages will be applied to a system is the way to go.